# Как сериализовать класс в Xml файл так, чтобы Класс с пустыми полями не записывался в тег

Tags: c#, сериализация

Допустим у меня есть такой класс, который нужно сериализовать

```
            public class OP
        {

            [XmlElement("ID")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("TIP_OP")]
            public string Tip_op { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("PERSON")]
            public PERSON Person { get; set; } 


             public OP()
             {
                Person = new PERSON();
             } 
         }
```

Класс PERSON допустим такой

```
  public class PERSON
        {
            [XmlElement("FAM")]
            public string Fam { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("IM")]
            public string Im { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("OT")]
            public string Ot { get; set; }
```

Потом сериализую таким образом

```
       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(FileName, false, encoding))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, SerializableObject, ns);
        }
```

Но на выходе, если у класса Person все поля пустые,  часть xml с этим полем выглядит так:

```html
<PERSON>
</PERSON>
```

А мне нужно, чтобы в этом случае вообще тэга PERSON не было. Можно вручную проверять все поля на пустоту, потом присваивать NULL, но нужен более нормальный способ. И ещё, в PERSON могут быть так-же вложенные классы, и в тех ещё вложенные , такая матрёшка, что усложняет запись в лоб проверки всех полей. Что посоветуете?

Моя попытка рефлексии

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo item in op.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyInfo propInfo =item;
                object obj = propInfo.GetValue(op);
                string s="";                  
// это называется я не нашёл как проверить является ли объект строкой, и решил 
// с заведомо известной строкой сравнивать =)
                if (obj.GetType()!= s.GetType())
                {

                }

            }
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону  DTO модели, и в ней зашить необходимое условие и сериализавать не сам класс, а dto!

Comment: так может имеет смысл для начала выбрать элементы которые необходимо сериализовать, а то сами себе проблему создаете)

Comment: А еще можете реализовать свойство ShouldSerialize{PropertyName} , с условием для сериализации.

Comment: pasha goroshko -
 В некоторых  экземплярах класса есть поля у PERSON, в некоторых нету, то-бишь такой, необязательный элемент, но если есть. сериализовать нужно.

Comment: Yury Bakharev-
Про ShouldSerialize знаю, но там ведь тоже придётся вручную проверку реализовывать  аля
'
public bool ShouldSerializePerson() 
{ return Person.Fam != null && Person.Im != null ..... ; }
'
А насчёт DTO не слышал, но т.к. сам проект довольно большой, полагаю что слишком хлопотно будет всю концепцию менять

Comment: Ну где то что-то написать в любом случае придётся, если структура сильно большая то можно рефлексивный метод кодинга применить, но это если она прям вообще BigData!

Comment: *И ещё, в PERSON могут быть так-же вложенные классы, и в тех ещё вложенные , такая матрёшка, что усложняет запись в лоб проверки всех полей. Что посоветуете?* — в таких случаях используют рефлексию

Comment: Я пробовал поразбираться с рефлексией, набросал (добавил в пост, гляньте), пользуясь тем, что все поля, которые не экзэмпляры вложенного класса, это строки, таким образом могу найти пустые строки,но это для первого уровня вложенности, а если там будет 3 и больше? На ум приходит только выписать это в отдельный метод и использовать рекурсию. но я с ней с универа так и не подружился)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере вы можете под каждым полем прописать ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}, это стандартный способ не сериализавать какое-либо свойство. И Да. В каждом методе нужно прописать условия для сериализации. Будьте внимательны если это Attribute то на сколько мне известно ShouldSerialize{PropertyName} не сработает!

```
public class PERSON
{
    [XmlElement("FAM")]
    public string Fam { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IM")]
    public string Im { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("OT")]
    public string Ot { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeFam()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fam);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeIm()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Im);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeOt()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ot);
    }
}
```

В комментариях вам советуют использовать рефлексию для создания таких методов. Я не знаю способов как это можно сделать на уровне самой сериализации(если только не использовать напрямую объект XmlSerializer,  а рефлексивно создавать XML, проверяя каждое поле). Но возможен и другой путь, вы можете поменять классы вашей модели, используя рекурсию и рефлексию для генерации кода, у меня нет времени писать полноценное ядро для такого перевода, да и это нужно делать обладая полными знаниями вашей структуры данных, но принцип примерно такой

```
   public void Foo()
    {
        OP target = new OP();
        var propertys = target.GetType().GetProperties();
        List<string> newFiles = new List<string>();
        SharedClasses(target.GetType().Name, propertys, ref newFiles);
    }
    public void SharedClasses(string className, PropertyInfo[] propertys, ref List<string> newFiles)
    {
        string res = "public class " + className + "\r\n";            
        res += "{" + "\r\n";
        foreach (var prop in propertys)
        {

            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                res += "    " + prop.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault().ToString() + "\r\n";
                res += "     public string " + prop.Name + "{get; set;} \r\n";

                res += "    " + " public bool ShouldSerialize" + prop.Name + "()\r\n";
                res += "    {" + "\r\n";
                res += "    " + "return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(" + prop.Name + ");\r\n";
                res += "    }\r\n";
            }
            else//Тут могут быть разные условия по типам, а так же создания конструкторов и т д
            {
                res += "    " + prop.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault().ToString() + "\r\n";
                res += "     public " + prop.PropertyType + " " + prop.Name + "{get; set;} \r\n";
                SharedClasses(prop.PropertyType.Name, prop.PropertyType.GetProperties(), ref newFiles);
            }
        }
        res += "}\r\n";
        newFiles.Add(res);
    }
```